# Recovering deleted rows from oracle table

Tags: oracle

Is this possible to recover the deleted rows from oracle table? My data is stored in a table MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS. Schema name is CCO.I have accidentally deleted some 500 Thousands rows in a table and did the commit too. Now I want to recover them.I am using Oracle 11g R2.Thanks

Comment: I have a couple of questions. 1)Do you have a backup containing the deleted records. 2) Do you have flashback enabled?

Comment: Thanks.I am very poor in database. I don't have any backup. I use TOAD to perform all my database operations. I don't know about FLASHBACK.

Comment: Please try Flashback as noted by Ravi Tiwari and ik_zelf If that does not work the last option I can think of would be a server backup. That should be a last resort option.

Answer (score 20):

You can recover the details using Oracle Flashback Query. 
You could query the contents of the table as of a time before the deletion to find out what data had been lost, and, if appropriate, re-insert the lost data in the database.
Here's the sample query:

```
select * from MANUAL_TRANSACTION as of timestamp to_timestamp('28-APR-2014 12:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') where ' clause based on your deleted data';
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr002.htm

Comment: I get this error. Lookup Error
ORA-08186: invalid timestamp specified

Comment: In what format are you trying to insert the timestamp?

Comment: Replace your AS OF clause with the following (no quotes):  "AS OF TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '120' MINUTE)"

Comment: I am not sure when my data was deleted. I assume that it is 3 days back. I changed the minutes accordingly but throws the following error .Lookup Error
ORA-01466: unable to read data - table definition has changed

Comment: @santhosha The error is quite possibly because of an DDL statement that altered the structure of your table.

Answer (score 13):

answers are already given just what i learned form above .
FLASHBACK can only be done by DBA( I guess ) but we can use below query

```
 Insert into MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS
    (SELECT * FROM MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS AS OF 
    TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-23 06:41:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'));
```

or you can go for this query **for one day records**

```
Insert into MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS
(SELECT * FROM MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS AS OF 
TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Comment: My table had a column with long datatype. Though I could see the deleted rows via select query based on timestamp but when I tried to insert the deleted row back in original table I got "SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype" .  Per the workaround given @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116396/workaround-for-ora-00997-illegal-use-of-long-datatype  I updated my column type to CLOB but now when I again ran your recovery query I got  "SQL Error: ORA-01466: unable to read data - table definition has changed".

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from MY_TABLE as of timestamp to_timestamp('04-MAY-2017 12:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') where ID=1822904;   --- 12Hr  Clock
```

Above query works for me. You can even look for 24Hr timeframe using  below query

```
select * from MY_TABLE as of timestamp to_timestamp('04-MAY-2017 13:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') where ID=1822904;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, use flash back query.
[Using Oracle Flashback Query (SELECT AS OF)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01003)
This assumes that the undo tablespace was big enough, with enough undo retention. If the undo is already freed, you might need to perform a restore and recovery, in a clone database and copy the data to the original database. Also check TSPITR, TableSpace Point In Time Recovery. This is only possible if your database runs in archivelog mode and has a backup available.

Answer (score 2):

If you have backup and Oracle 12c you could use `Table Point In Time Recovery` ([PITR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmresind.htm#BRADV686)):

```
RECOVER TABLE 'SCHEMA'.'TAB_NAME'
  UNTIL TIME xxxxyyy
  AUXILIARY DESTINATION '/u01/aux'  
  REMAP TABLE 'SCHEMA'.'TAB_NAME':'TAB_NAME_PREV';
```

Your data at that point in time will be available:

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TAB_NAME_PREV;
```

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME AS OF TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE - 4/24)

Comment: Please elaborate a little more on your question, just putting code can be hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late for the answer, after long search about how to recovery and restore tables in oracle I finally found a good way to restore by using `restore point`, according to [Pro Oracle Database 12C Administration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EQ9BO74) book, before any action into your table you could use `restore point` by using following lines:

```sql
CREATE RESTORE POINT <your_key_point_name>;
```

for recovery table with restore point you can use :

```sql
FLASHBACK TABLE <[your_schema.]your_table_name> TO RESTORE POINT <your_key_point_name>;
```

beside this all of above answers "about recovering using  `FLASHBACK`" forgot to consider two key points:

1. for using `FLASHBACK` recycle bin mode must be enabled
2. before any row recovery using `FLASHBACK` , row movement in your table must be enabled (with `ALTER TABLE <[your_schema.]your_table_name> enable ROW MOVEMENT`). According to oracle documents [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-64C48A91-42DF-4E07-834A-987802E1130D.htm):

> Before you can use Flashback Table, you must ensure that row movement is enabled on the table to be flashed back, or returned to a previous state.

Answer (score 0):

```
FLASHBACK TABLE <TABLE_NAME> TO TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE('27-APR-2014 23:59:59','DD-MON-YYYY HH24: MI: SS'));
```

Restores the data in the table to the given time(provided the table was not truncated).

In your case:

FLASHBACK TABLE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS TO TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE('27-APR-2014 23:59:59','DD-MON-YYYY HH24: MI: SS'));

Comment: This time error differs.Lookup Error
ORA-08189: cannot flashback the table because row movement is not enabled

Comment: Bad news. Flashback to a timestamp works only if row movement is enabled on that table

Answer (score 0):

Use this query,

```
Insert into MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS
(SELECT * FROM MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS AS OF 
TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-27 11:59:59 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'))
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer some?

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to remove the PM in the end.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options:

1. Flashback Query as

   create table before_delete as select * from Table as of TIMESTAMP XX;
2. Logminer if Oracle supplement log is enabled , you can get undo sql for your delete statement

-- switch again logfile to get a minimal redo activity
alter system switch logfile;

-- mine the last written archived log

```
exec dbms_logmnr.add_logfile('archivelog/redologfile', options => dbms_logmnr.new);
exec dbms_logmnr.start_logmnr(options => dbms_logmnr.dict_from_online_catalog);
select operation, sql_redo from v$logmnr_contents where seg_name = 'EMP';
```

3. Oracle PRM-DUL will be last option. Even deleted row piece in Oracle block is always just marked row flag with deleted mask, the row piece still can be read via scan Oracle data block . PRM-DUL can scan the whole table , find out every record/row piece marked deleted and write out to flat file.

Answer (score 0):

what you may try is :

1. flashback query,  available from oracle 10g  , may failed with ora-01555 snapshot too old
2. redo logminer , mine redo and may find undo sql
3. prm-dul tool ( a commercial recovery tool for oracle), which can scan oracle block and find even deleted row piece