# Workaround for ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes, sqllong

I want to save some data from a system table user_tab_cols, to a temp table so I can take a dump from it.

There are 100,000 rows in it , I have select from user_tab_cols about 1,000 records and d save them into a temp table with this query:

```
create table temp table as 
select * from user_tab_cols where condition...
```

I had error 'illegal use of longtype' , because of the column DATA_DEFAULT that contain a type of long.

Is there an alterantive way where I can store a long type into another table?

Comment: `long`s are extremely limited types. Is there any particular reason you aren't using `CLOB`s?

Comment: @Mureinik I am extracting some data from user_tab_cols which contain a column long , is there a way I can extract those data ?

Comment: Didn't register the table name... That was a stupid question on my behalf. Mea Culpa.

Comment: Use **TO_LOB** to convert it into CLOB. See my answer.

Comment: The SQL*Plus COPY command might help - used it before for Oracle-to-Oracle via DB Link for a table containing LONG. I do not know if it would work MySQL-to-Oracle. Other alternative might be to look at a Java Stored Procedure to open a connection to the remote db and fetch the data then insert locally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

It is a **restriction** on usage of **LONG** data type. *You cannot create an object type with a LONG attribute.*

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT data_default FROM user_tab_cols;
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT data_default FROM user_tab_cols
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype


SQL>
```

Alternatively, you could use **TO_LOB** as a workaround. Which would convert it into CLOB data type.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT TO_LOB(data_default) data_default FROM user_tab_cols;

Table created.

SQL> desc t;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DATA_DEFAULT                                       CLOB

SQL>
```

See more examples of workarounds [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create your target table explicitly, not from `select *`:

```
create table demo_copy
( table_name varchar2(30)
, column_name varchar2(30)
, data_type varchar2(106)
, data_type_mod varchar2(3)
, data_type_owner varchar2(30)
, data_length number
, data_precision number
, data_scale number
, nullable varchar2(1)
, column_id number
, default_length number
, data_default clob
, num_distinct number
, low_value raw(32)
, high_value raw(32)
, density number
, num_nulls number
, num_buckets number
, last_analyzed date
, sample_size number
, character_set_name varchar2(44)
, char_col_decl_length number
, global_stats varchar2(3)
, user_stats varchar2(3)
, avg_col_len number
, char_length number
, char_used varchar2(1)
, v80_fmt_image varchar2(3)
, data_upgraded varchar2(3)
, hidden_column varchar2(3)
, virtual_column varchar2(3)
, segment_column_id number
, internal_column_id number
, histogram varchar2(15)
, qualified_col_name varchar2(4000) );
```

(I've made `data_default` a `clob` for more convenient querying.)

Then you can insert rows in a PL/SQL loop:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select * from user_tab_cols c
        where  rownum <= 2  -- your filter condition here
    )
    loop
        insert into demo_copy values r;
    end loop;
end;
```

There are some limitations in principle with this approach, as a `long` column can hold more than the `varchar2(32760)` that PL/SQL will use in the loop. However, I expect 32K will be enough for most column default expressions.