# Illegal use of LONG datatype Oracle

Tags: oracle, ora-00997

this is my firt question here

I have a problem trying to convert a table column (long raw) to a base 64 string, this column contains some of the employees pictures.

This is the query, the field that i'm trying to convert is **f.fot_empl**:

```
SELECT e.NOM_EMPL First_name,
       APE_EMPL Last_name,
       e.NOM_EMPL || ' ' || e.APE_EMPL Full_name,
       car.NOM_CARG position,
       COS.NOM_CCOS Area,
       f.fot_empl Picture, 
       E.FEC_NACI Birth_date
  FROM EMPLE e
       INNER JOIN CONTR c
          ON E.COD_EMPL = C.COD_EMPL
       INNER JOIN cargo car
          ON C.COD_CARG = CAR.COD_CARG
       INNER JOIN CCOST cos
        on COS.COD_CCOS = C.COD_CCOS
       LEFT JOIN FOEMP f -- employee picture
          ON e.cod_empl = F.COD_EMPL
 WHERE C.IND_ACTI = 'A';
```

**What i have tried:**

The accepted answer of this post with no results, i keep getting "Illegal use of LONG datatype" error.
[Workaround for ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116396/workaround-for-ora-00997-illegal-use-of-long-datatype)

I try to implement the following function with no results:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_base64 (
       vcodem     IN FOEMP.COD_EMPR%TYPE,
       vcodempl   IN FOEMP.COD_EMPL%TYPE)
       RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
       V_VAR      FOEMP.FOT_EMPL%TYPE;
       V_result   VARCHAR2 (4000);
    BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Start');
       SELECT UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (
                 UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (
                    UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (f.FOT_EMPL, 4000))))
         INTO V_result
         FROM FOEMP f
        WHERE COD_EMPL = vcodempl AND COD_EMPR = vcodem;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('End');
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Result: ' || V_result);
    END to_base64;
    /
```

The function is invalid due to ORA-00997 in:

```
   SELECT UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (
             UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (
                UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (f.FOT_EMPL, 4000))))
     INTO V_result
     FROM FOEMP f
    WHERE COD_EMPL = vcodempl AND COD_EMPR = vcodem;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: if f.fot_empl is a long_Raw, why are you using dbms_lob.substr against it? (it would need to be a lob first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

1. given the many problems i had with long raw i decide to create a
   table like this:

   `CREATE TABLE FOTS_EMPL ( cod_empr, cod_empl, foto)
       AS
          SELECT F.COD_EMPR, F.COD_EMPL, TO_LOB (FOT_EMPL)
            FROM FOEMP f;`
2. i took the function given by @tbone and i added and if condition
   like this:

   `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base64enc (p_blob IN BLOB)
      RETURN CLOB
   AS
      l_clob   CLOB;
      l_step   PLS_INTEGER := 1998;
   BEGIN
      IF p_blob IS NOT NULL 
      THEN
         FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC ( (DBMS_LOB.getlength (p_blob) - 1) / l_step)
         LOOP
            l_clob :=
                  l_clob
               || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (
                     UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (
                        DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (p_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1)));
         END LOOP;
         RETURN l_clob;
      ELSE
         RETURN NULL;
      END IF;
   END base64enc;`
3. this was my final select statement:

   `SELECT e.NOM_EMPL First_name,
                  APE_EMPL Last_name,
                  e.NOM_EMPL || ' ' || e.APE_EMPL Full_name,
                  car.NOM_CARG position,
                  COS.NOM_CCOS Area,
                  base64enc(foto) Picture, 
                  E.FEC_NACI Birth_date
             FROM EMPLE e
                  INNER JOIN CONTR c
                     ON E.COD_EMPL = C.COD_EMPL
                  INNER JOIN cargo car
                     ON C.COD_CARG = CAR.COD_CARG
                  INNER JOIN CCOST cos
                   on COS.COD_CCOS = C.COD_CCOS
                  LEFT JOIN FOTS_EMPL F -- new table with blob instead of long raw
                   ON e.cod_empl = F.COD_EMPL AND e.cod_empr = f.cod_empr
            WHERE C.IND_ACTI = 'A';`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your LONG RAW value into a BLOB in a PL/SQL block, and then base64-encode that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_base64 (
   vcodem     IN FOEMP.COD_EMPR%TYPE,
   vcodempl   IN FOEMP.COD_EMPL%TYPE)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_blob BLOB;
  l_long_raw LONG RAW;
BEGIN
  SELECT fot_empl INTO l_long_raw
    FROM foemp
   WHERE COD_EMPL = vcodempl AND COD_EMPR = vcodem;
  l_blob := TO_BLOB(l_long_raw);
  RETURN UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (l_blob));
END;
/
```

Of course, [strongly recommends that you convert LONG RAW columns to binary LOB (BLOB) columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref179); still storing data as LONG or LONG raw seems rather antiquated now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm still getting the error when i try to execute the select statement or call the function:

`to_base64(f.fot_empl) Picture`

Comment: @diegofer11 - as with your version, you need to pass in the key fields to look up the row to get the long value. `select to_base64(x, y) from dual`, or `select codempl, codempr, to_base64(codempl, codempr) picture from foemp`. Which isn't ideal, but one of the restrictions of using an old data type. Also tbone is probably right about chopping the BLOB up, I didn't try with any large values.

Answer (score 1):

SQL binds at most 4000 for varchar2 and 2000 for char.  raw is a binary char, so I would encode in chunks of just under 2k, something like:

```
create or replace FUNCTION base64enc(p_blob IN BLOB) RETURN CLOB
    AS
      l_clob CLOB;
      l_step PLS_INTEGER := 1998;
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
        l_clob := l_clob || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1)));
      END LOOP;
      RETURN l_clob;
END base64enc;
```

Now that you have the base64enc function, you'd pass in your (converted) blob and store CLOBs.

An example might be:

```
create table t1 ( id int primary key, x long raw )

insert into t1 values( 1, rpad( 'a', 2000, 'a' ) )
commit;

create or replace function convertLR(i_id in int)
return clob
as
  l_blob blob;
  l_longraw long raw;
begin
  select x into l_longraw from t1 where id = i_id;
  l_blob := to_blob(l_longraw);
  return base64enc(l_blob);
end;

select convertLR(1) from dual;
```